# При вожу производителя, тип, диагональ, и потом ошибка System.FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#

Чё тут не так? я вообще не понимаю, у меня два класс.
Ошибка находятся в Program.cs, 26 строк

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace laba17
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ML list = new ML();
            string inpug = "", firm, type, diagonale;
            int counter = 0;
            while (inpug != "нет")
            {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine($"Ввод значения {counter}");
                Console.Write("Введите производителя: ");
                firm = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Введите тип: ");
                type = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Введите диагональ: ");
                diagonale = Console.ReadLine();
                list.Add(new SH(firm, type, Convert.ToDouble(diagonale)));
                Console.Write("Продолжить? [\"нет\" если хотите завершить ввод]: ");
                inpug = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
            }

            string choise;
            while (true)
            {
                list.vivestiall();
                Console.WriteLine($"Текущая позиция в списке: {list.position}");
                Console.Write("Выберите действие:\n[1] - Задать позицию\n[2] - Добавить элемент\n[3] - Изменить текущий элемент\n[4] - Удалить текущий элемент\n[5] - Отсортировать список по цене\nВаш выбор: ");
                choise = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                if (choise == "1")
                {
                    Console.Write("Введите новую текущую позицию: ");
                    list.position = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine($"Новая позиция установлена ({list.position}).");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else if (choise == "2")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ввод нового значения");
                    Console.Write("Введите производителя: ");
                    firm = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите тип: ");
                    type = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите диагональ: ");
                    diagonale = Console.ReadLine();
                    list.Add(new SH(firm, type, Convert.ToDouble(diagonale)));
                    Console.WriteLine("Новая запись добавлена.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else if (choise == "3")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Редактирование значения {list.position}");
                    Console.Write("Введите производителя: ");
                    firm = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите размер: ");
                    type = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Введите цену: ");
                    diagonale = Console.ReadLine();
                    list.positionfirm(firm, type, Convert.ToDouble(diagonale));
                    Console.WriteLine($"Запись №{list.position} отредактирована.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else if (choise == "4")
                {
                    list.delete();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Запись №{list.position} удалена.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Выбранно несуществующее значение.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace laba17
{
    class ML
    {
        private LinkedList<SH> list;
        public int position;

        public ML()
        {
            list = new LinkedList<SH>();
            position = 1;
        }

        public void Add(SH s)
        {
            list.AddLast(s);
        }
        public void positionfirm(string Firm, string Type, double Diagonale)
        {
            LinkedListNode<SH> dir = list.First;
            for (int i = 1; i < position; i++)
            {
                dir = dir.Next;
            }
            dir.Value = new SH(Firm, Type, Diagonale);
        }
        public void delete()
        {
            LinkedListNode<SH> dir = list.First;
            for(int i = 1; i < position; i++)
            {
                dir = dir.Next;
            }
            list.Remove(dir);
        }
        public void vivestiall()
        {
            int position1 = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("\tФирма\tТип\tДиагональ");
            foreach(SH s in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{position1}{s.Firm}\t{s.Type}\t{s.Diagonale}");
                position1++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace laba17
{
    public class SH : ICloneable
    {
        public string Firm;
        public string Type;
        public double Diagonale;

        public SH() { }

        public SH(string Firm, string Type, double Diagonale) 
        {
            this.Firm = Firm;
            this.Type = Type;
            this.Diagonale = Diagonale;
        }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return new SH(Firm, Type, Diagonale);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Фирма - {Firm}; Тип - {Type}; Диагональ - {Diagonale}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш ввод, при котором выходит эта ошибка.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая ошибка возникает в том случае если содержимое локальной переменной `diagonale` невозможно преобразовать в тип `double`. Например, вместо `5,6` написать `5.6`.

```
Console.Write("Введите диагональ: ");
diagonale = Console.ReadLine();
list.Add(new SH(firm, type, Convert.ToDouble(diagonale))); <--- Здесь
```

Для проверки используйте TryParse(String, Double).

Либо вводите правильно число, либо измените код.

Например так:

```
do
{
    Console.Write("Введите диагональ: ");
} while (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out diagonale));
list.Add(new SH(firm, type, diagonale));
```

Измените тип переменной diagonale на double.

Comment: Это как делать?
Я вообще не понятно